# How to politely return an expensive gift from a coworker?

Tags: colleagues, cultural-sensitivity

One of my team members gave me an expensive gift before the Christmas break as a thank you for something that I did for him earlier in the year. I feel it's way over the top and would like to give it back without causing any tensions or hard feelings.

Long story: Earlier in the year my coworker wanted to start working with a new technology but didn't have the required experience. I knew that he's a fast learner and would quickly get up to speed. As I've been in the company for years, I managed to pull some strings and talked to the right people and got him placed on a project where he got hands on with the tech he wanted. It was no big deal from my perspective, it didn't cost me any money, and I was happy to help him progress his career in the direction he wanted.

However, now he gave me a prepaid voucher for an all inclusive dinner for two in a very expensive restaurant. I know it must be worth well over $500, possibly a lot more. I wouldn't mind if he bought me a lunch at work or gave me a box of chocolates or something in that price range, but this is way too much. I don't think it's appropriate for the little favour that I did for him. And at the back of my mind, I somehow worry that it would put me in a position where I "owe him" something, even though he probably doesn't see it that way.

To complicate the matter some more, we're from different cultural backgrounds - I am a European and he's from India.

I don't want to cause him a disappointment. I don't know how, as an Indian, he would take this, but, at the same time, I don't really want to accept a gift this expensive. What do I do?

Comment: Is it possible that your coworker has a connection (family possibly?) with this restaurant and was able to get the voucher for significantly less then its "face value"? Or perhaps is "re-gifting" it to you due to not being able to use it themselves due to something like dietary or religious reasons?

Comment: You would really be stomping on his ego if you declined the gift. Is that what you want to do? Eat, drink, and be merry is my advice.

Comment: @AsheraH I wouldn't.

Comment: I agree that you have a valid concern (as you were probably his manager ?) You wrote "**I wouldn't mind if he bought me a lunch at work or gave me a box of chocolates or something in that price range**". So, have you tried to explain your concern to him, and ask him to exchange the prepaid voucher for something else that costs less ? **That way, it does not hurt his feeling because you still accept another gift from him**. -- BTW, if that prepaid voucher is not refundable, and if he accepts that prepaid voucher back, he could enjoy a nice dinner with his family. :-)

Comment: @AsheraH it's a possibility that the gift giver is looking for a romantic relationship, in which case going out on for dinner would be a really, really bad idea.

Comment: Have you checked your company's gift policy? You may be able to back out of the gift pointing to that. Many companies have internal policies around gift giving.

Answer (score 14):

I am assuming you are in a typically regulated Western company. Other rules may apply in other locations.

I never accept any gifts beyond a coffee or at best an invitation to a simple refectory-level lunch as thank you from colleagues. Keep it under control. Sliding to larger gifts is, even under the best of intentions, problematic. Introducing a high-value gifting culture is an invitation for abuse, even if not in the concrete case of you and your colleague. Even if your company is a paradigm for integrity, one should not put its virtues to the test unless absolutely necessary.

If you agree with my above premise, accepting the gift was a mistake in the first place. However, now it's done.

[Modified after insightful comment by Old Padawan] If there is no hard rule/regulation that requires you to provide transparency and to declare the gift, the best would be to discreetly return it.

Think of it as follows: if there is no such rule against gifting, you do not want your case, were it to become known, to be the reason for it to be introduced.

It is very unfortunate that, under the rules of their culture, your colleague wanted to signal their great appreciation of your help, but in the end of the day, you have to operate under the customs of the place you are working in. Inappropriate gifts have the potential create a serious amount of trouble in the long run, even if given under innocent presumptions. There are cultural quirks one can easily sail with, this is not one of them.

Comment: Don't you think involving a manager right away is inappropriate? I mean, this colleague is just trying to be nice and shows appreciation, and you ante up *that* much? Once management is in, it's going to be difficult to keep a good relationship and your reputation might also suffer behind your back... Just my 2 cents asking for clarification though

Comment: @OldPadawan Let's put it this way, maybe there is regulation in place where OP *must* declare the gift anyway; OP may not be aware of that. The manager may know. However, I agree with you, the better way were to sort it out privately. It will be challenging, however, for OP to return the gift after accepting it without offending the giver. It would have been much easier to decline in the first place. I will put in a caveat.

Comment: @OldPadawan Modified my text. You have a point with the manager who may not always be a helpful figure. Is it better now?

Answer (score 5):

Honestly?

I'd keep the restaurant voucher, go out to dinner, enjoy myself...

And then for the next few weeks when it's lunchtime be sure to shout my co-worker the cost of lunch until such time as you feel that you've evened up the balance sheet sufficiently between you.

However to add something else - have you considered the impact that your recommendation, trust and guidance is likely to have had on his personal and professional growth?

What to you is nothing more than a good word here and there and a name drop, to him could literally be a pivotal moment in their life - the chance to do something they've always wanted to do - just to be given a shot.

Can you truly put a Dollar value on such an opportunity, and assuming you could, would it be as little as $500?

Comment: +1 I second this. Being from Pakistan (which is relevant here as your gifter is from India) I don't think he would feel like now you owe him anything. He probably did what he feel right. So enjoy the gift. As per his (and mine) culture he is not doing anything out of ordinary. Infact he would be expected to do something similar, something substantial and buying you a lunch as you said would be considered disrespectful to you actually (something like that is done for beggars / people who ask for help, not for people who have helped).

Comment: They problem is you may not want to spend all that money. You're making it into a white elephant.

Comment: Ugh, dangerous advice. Most companies severely restrict the acceptance of gifts in relation to your employment (yes, also from colleagues) - violating this may result in being fired. In some countries, accepting such gifts may even be a crime. Definitively do not accept the gift unless you are 100% sure this does not violate company policy or laws.

Comment: Sorry, but a $500 gift would count as not okay in a European corporate setting. It doesn't matter that the favor OP granted could be worth a lot more than $500 to the gift giver. There might be a cultural clash here and this could hurt the gift givers feelings but in the setting where OP is this is just not acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly a pickle.

Some answers and comments suggest that the good you've done his career may tally with the scale of the gift, but that is not the only question.

The question is also whether this would be an *appropriate kind of reciprocation* for that kind of career benefit.

Most in developed nations would say this kind of reciprocation is a corrupt one, and that to indulge private gift-giving on that scale would be to eventually encourage a system of graft and bribery that dogs the bureaucracies of less developed nations.

It may be necessary to establish first how much the vouchers actually cost - perhaps state your own estimate of $500, and then relate that to what you might reasonably regard as the highest suggestion for a private token of appreciation. At least, if he didn't buy them for anything near their apparent value, or if your estimate is quite mistaken, then there is an opportunity for him to explain that.

Since there may be a difference of cultural background, it might also be necessary to emphasise the modest nature of what was required of you to provide the favour, and that your employer is amongst the beneficiaries of your colleague being matched to work he is good at.

You can also talk about how a more appropriate way to settle the favour is for him to repay the favour in kind to you in a work context, such as making an extra effort if you ever asked for his help at work, or to "pay it forward" in small amounts to a number of others in future, in honour of the benefit he once received from you.

These tend to be approaches toward reciprocation that promote organisational goals and a healthy culture.

Many organisations have "bribery policies" and limits on private gifts, but it's unfortunate that they rarely explain the logic of the policy in this fashion - probably because many of those writing them have no grasp of the logic themselves.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I suspect the intended meaning is closer to "While many  organisations have "bribery policies" and limits on private gifts, it's unfortunate that they rarely explain the logic of the policy in this fashion"

Comment: @CaptainEmacs, thank heavens you didn't downvote! See ClumsyCat's clarification.

Comment: @Steve Ok, my comment becomes obsolete and is now deleted.

Comment: If it would cost OP $500 to pay themselves for the dinner that the voucher entitles them to, than that is the value of the gift. It doesn't matter if the gift giver may have gotten it for a much lower price because he has some cousin working there or something like that. That would just mean the gift giver received a favor worth several hundred $ from the cousin but that doesn't change anything for OP.

Comment: @quarague, I think the actual cost to the giver can change the situation. For example, a gift may have a market value when purchased from source, but an unwanted gift already received may have considerably lower value and marketability, if the person wanted to dispose of the unwanted gift for cash. Giving this away to repay a favour, and the receiver getting it on the understanding that it was not purchased at market value, tends to suggest a much lower value than the market value is being conveyed.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, in order to not hurt my colleague's feelings, I would definitely keep the gift for the moment while checking with the company's policy about gifts. I've met/worked with great people from Eastern cultures (from Lebanon, India, Indonesia, China...) and I know for sure they would be deeply hurt in case you refuse it. In some culture, it's even an insult.

What I would then quickly do is to check my company's policy about gifts. If it has a maximum amount or not, then you'll have options depending on the policy/amount:

1. inform your colleague about that, and explain how sorry you are to have to return the gift, so neither of you is in trouble.
2. use the gift and enjoy.

***IF*** there's no company's policy about gifts, you also have another option, but it can be a tricky one, so think about it and take it with a grain of salt: the people I knew would have been too polite/shy to ask for feedback about the gift, so keep the voucher in a drawer at your desk without using it.

Comment: Good answer - however I feel the "another option" part is dangerous: If policy forbids you from accepting the gift, keeping and not using it will probably still violate the policy - so I don't see how this option makes sense.

Comment: @sleske : no, the "another option" *might* exists ***if*** there's no company policy about gifts, that's why it's not included in the bullet list

Comment: Whether the gifter from a different culture sees a insult or not: de facto there are *very* significant taboos also in the culture in which OP works (I assume it's western): inappropriate gifts are one of them. I think it is perfectly ok for OP to invoke that taboo rule. There is no reason why cultural demands/taboos of the gifter should override those of the receiver. The declining of the gift, if OP so decides, should be done in a maximally polite way, but there is no good justification why the gifter's cultural quirks should supersede the receiver's.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs : I'm not saying culture should in any case override the law/rule of the company. I just mention that cultural thing to say "*be **very very** careful*" when declining/returning.

Comment: @OldPadawan Your answer says "I would keep ... for the moment" - that's not just very very careful careful, that's giving priority to the others' culture. If you would work the latter into your answer, I might agree.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs @ sleske : I've modified my answer to clarify the points we discussed, better when you read it like that?

Comment: @OldPadawan A bit better. I still do not agree that the decision of returning it depends on the policy. $500 is a substantial amount for in-office gifts, even if there is no explicit policy. As stated in my answer: if this transaction were known, might it trigger a new regulation? If yes, it's too much (maybe not in an office where everyone has bone white businesscards with embossed print and gets a reservation at Dorsia...)

Answer (score 2):

It isn't for us to place a "value" on the gifts others give us. Your coworker obviously believes that his gift to you is appropriate and is an expression of the value that **he** places on your assistance. Honor his appreciation by being gracious and accepting it without any further ado.

People will often want to give me "something" for my time, even if I think that what I did for them was trivial. I graciously accept it because by doing so, I'm honoring the value they've placed on my assistance.

Comment: This may be a bit unclear. I enjoy buying Christmas gifts that have much lower cost than value. Obviously "cost" is _my_ cost, and "value" is _the receiver's_ value. So in the situation here I might have decided for myself that I want to spend £100, but finding a gift that has a value of £500 for the receiver while costing me only £100 would make me very happy.

Answer (score 2):

Very similar story to what happened with me. I was contracting at a bank in Toronto, and a new full-time employee, recently from India, was (without it being said explicitly) hired to replace me. I spent a lot of time freely sharing knowledge and pretty much knew that the bank wanted to replace me with a lower cost full-timer; I did not mind, as I was rightfully confident I could find new opportunities with my experience, skills, and knowledge. In general, I believe in sharing knowledge freely.

So, close to my last day, this person, who has a very kind heart, gave me $100 in cash! I did not want to insult him, so I quietly accepted the gift. Then, later, I spoke to my manager, and asked him to return the money to this person. I would have felt awful keeping the money (especially being such a large amount, and this person was a recent immigrant with a family living in an expensive city). I would have felt like a jerk if I had kept the money.

In sum, my suggestion: have your manager or HR return the gift. You do not need it; you are smart and have marketable skills. That person probably still needs the money that was used to purchase that gift.

Comment: I won an expensive meal for two in a raffle. Unfortunately my wife doesn’t like their food, so I gave the voucher to a very helpful colleague. A week later HR returns the voucher to me. I think “WTF”?

Comment: @gnasher729 the typical custom in Canadian and American companies is that it is inappropriate to gift a colleague, at work, with anything more than a trivial item (eg: $10 gift card for Starbucks). To regift a voucher for an expensive meal might make the receiver feel very uncomfortable, as though something might be expected in return. If HR returned the voucher, it would be a "what did you expect in this country" kind of lesson for the giver. Someone moving to Canada or USA needs to learn the work culture norms of their new home.

Answer (score 1):

An approach I can recommend is to donate the voucher to a charity that you support (and preferably that wouldn't be offensive to your colleague). This gives you the opportunity to recognise the value of the gift that you have been given and not reject it (by implication rejecting your colleague).
Charities are often looking for gifts like this that can be auctioned off for a fundraiser.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that he wants you to have this gift. Take it, enjoy yourself, and keep a note that if he needs a favour, you should do him the favour. And tell him that he was very, very generous.

Any gift has a cost, and a value. The cost to him might be much less than the value to you. He might have connections to the restaurant. He might have gone to a site that sells vouchers quite cheaply. He might have won the voucher in a raffle and don't care about Indian restaurants. Horrible case that he bought the voucher for himself and his girlfriend before she became his ex-girlfriend.

Comment: "Take it, enjoy yourself, and keep a note that if he needs a favour, you should do him the favour" sounds like text book corruption.

Comment: @Llewellyn You have a very corrupt fantasy.

Comment: Yesterday, a colleague asked me for a favour. So I brought him a sandwich when I went to the sandwich shop. Apparently that was corruption.

Comment: @gnasher729 I usually like to read your practical and to-the-point advice. However, 500$ is not 5$ for a sandwich. These are two orders of magnitude away, and the favours that might be implied, quite on different scales, too. Not a good comparison.

Answer (score -2):

To me, there are a couple of questions before diving into whether or not the gift is appropriate.

Some workplaces do have gift limits in order to prevent workplace conflicts. When I moved to my current location my house came with appliances which are typically moved with the owner, but which are left with the house where I now live. This left me with a spare washer, dryer and refrigerator. I had my hands full, and didn't want to waste time trying to sell them on-line, so I asked around at work. A coworker needed them for a family member, so I gave them to him. I made sure my manager knew what I was doing. He didn't care and said it was okay.

The best way to overcome any questions of workplace impropriety are to make sure your manager (or HR) knows what's going on.

Another respondent said that you can never know the value someone else places on a favor. It is very likely that he believes you've completely changed his career direction, and that makes it an invaluable favor. I helped a colleague get his career moving about 15 years ago and today he's in an excellent position. We've stayed in touch over the years and I have no doubt he viewed my help as transformational.

Unless you are somehow embarrassed by his generosity, my suggestion is this:

Write him a thank-you note and copy both your manager and his. Tell him how honored you feel (I assume you do) that you were able to help him and that you look forward to hearing what he's doing with the opportunity you provided. Mentoring co-workers, and helping others find opportunities is a leadership skill. The value, to you, will be seeing how your efforts helped change his career. It's a really good feeling when your kindness pays off.

It's very unlikely that a more senior employee who's not in a management position will have a conflict of interest over a gift. Enjoy the dinner and stay in touch with him. I'm sure that over time you'll see that the value of the gift paled in comparison to the value he received.

Comment: Involving a manager could be the least thing that does any good in this situation. Imagine you want to make somone happy - and this person informs your manager because it's inappropriate. This is a very bad idea in my opinion.

Comment: "it's very unlikely that a more senior employee who's not in a management position will have a conflict of interest over a gift" - dangerous advice. Even if not in a management position, the employee may have other influence, e.g. over assignment of work tasks, of equipment, or of training (as in this case). Also, there may well be company policy which forbids this.

Comment: @puck - "Involving a manager could be the least thing that does any good in this situation. Imagine you want to make somone happy - and this person informs your manager because it's inappropriate. This is a very bad idea in my opinion."

That's why you make sure the manager is involved.

Imagine someone wants to make another someone happy. And they break the rules. And you both get caught. And then you both get fired.

I've done this before. This is the correct approach. Read the example I gave above of major appliances.